# Pass a new argument in JavaScript code to target HTML attributes

Tags: javascript, html, custom-data-attribute, modularity

I currently have created a piece of Javascript code which checks an HTTP response and if its a successful 200 code the traffic light shows green and if its not a 200 code the traffic light flashes red.

My current problem at the moment is I want to be able to pass **Two** arguments to the initializing function like so

```
requestResponses.init('/status', "ATTR");
```

The first attribute being the URL I want to test against and the second attribute being the value of the HTML **data-request** attribute I have created.

My reason for this as I want to have multiple traffic lights on the same page targeting different URLs simultaneously without effecting each other.

So for Example I create a data request attribute and give it a value of **Four** I then want to be able to hook it up like so

```
requestResponses.init('/status', "Four");
```

and start targeting elements like below within the code. This makes it that bit more modular and reusable.

```
.cp_trafficLight[data-request="Four"]
```

Please find my code attached and a working JSFiddle.

```
    var requestResponses = {

    greenLight: $('.cp_trafficLight_Light--greenDimmed'),
    redLight: $('.cp_trafficLight_Light--redDimmed'),
    greenBright: 'cp_trafficLight_Light--greenBright',
    redBright: 'cp_trafficLight_Light--redBright',

    settings: {
        flashError: 400,
        requestTime: 10000
    },

    init: function (url, targAttr) {
        requestResponses.url = url;
        requestResponses.getResponse(requestResponses.url, targAttr);
        setInterval(function () {
            if (requestResponses.errorCode === true) {
                requestResponses.redLight.toggleClass(requestResponses.redBright);
            }
        }, requestResponses.settings.flashError);
    },

    successResponse: function (targAttr) {
        requestResponses.errorCode = false;
        requestResponses.redLight.removeClass(requestResponses.redBright);
        requestResponses.greenLight.addClass(requestResponses.greenBright);
        console.log(targAttr);
    },

    errorResponse: function (targAttr) {
        requestResponses.greenLight.removeClass(requestResponses.greenBright);
    },

    getResponse: function (serverURL, targAttr) {
        $.ajax(serverURL, {
            success: function () {
                requestResponses.errorCode = false;
                requestResponses.successResponse(targAttr);
            },
            error: function () {
                requestResponses.errorCode = true;
                requestResponses.errorResponse(targAttr);
            },
            complete: function () {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    requestResponses.getResponse(requestResponses.url);
                }, requestResponses.settings.requestTime);
            }
        });
    },

    errorCode: false
}

requestResponses.init('/status', "TEST");
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8700h582/

Answer (score 0):

Then in your function you include a second parameter separated with a comma.

```
function foo(param1, param2) {

    //Do something.

};

foo("1st", "2nd");
```

**EDIT** 
i see now in your init include the second param for the light and in the init function pass this second param to your request and then from there pass it down to your error and respons function. And then return the function. That can be held in a var.

Comment: I get that but my problem is this parameter isn't passable to another function?

Comment: @Rebecca i don't get what you mean. You mean calling foo within another function?

Comment: so I want to be able to pass this argument into the "errorResponse" and the "successResponse" method so I can begin to manipulate the dom. Each Attribute will be unique to each Traffic Light.

Comment: Then what your trying to do is create a factory that returns a function on it's propertys. You should look up how prototypes work. That will get you in the right direction.

Comment: Sure. Do you have an example of this and I will mark your answer correct :)

Comment: I'm on a smart phone so writing/editing code is tricky or else i would just edit yours.

Comment: I appreciate your help Darkrum. I have edited my code and posted it below but the result is "undefined" could you tell me why? I hope I followed your instructions correctly.